# How to configure annotations processing in IntelliJ IDEA 14 for current project work?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

The structure of the project is:

- Parent project

  - A project (Spring) have dependency of project B in pom.xml
  - B project (Spring MVC) have dependency of project A in pom.xml

After launching project B in Tomcat 7, I have an error:

> Error:java: Annotation processing is not supported for module cycles.
>   Please ensure that all modules from cycle [A,B] are excluded from
>   annotation processing

How do I avoid this problem?

I use Java 8, Tomcat 7 and Intellij Idea 14.

Comment: For me, IntelliJ IDEA doesn't seem to understand the test scope, thinking it's a cyclic dependency. Example: B->A and A[test]->B and of course A[test]->A. No cyclic dependency here.

Comment: Opened a defect - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159568.

Comment: A year and 3 months later, the defect is still open. Are tests a 2nd class citizen in IDEA?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To solve these kind of problems need to use Analyze Module dependencies in InteliJ-idea.

File Menu > Analyze > Module Dependencies

This shows the list of all projects which have cyclic dependencies and should be resolved first.

This feature helps you to find the problem.

**EDIT** – For the latest version, it is **Analyze -> Analyze Module Dependencies..**

Comment: Just FYI, in recent InteliJ IDEA versions (e.g. 2017.x) try: 
Analyze > Analyze Module Dependencies..,

Comment: this is the right approach overall to analyze dependencies. @codepleb's answer below is useful to fix this problem. thanks to both you guys!

Comment: For me it was File Menu > Analyze > Analyze Cyclic Dependencies

Comment: Could somebody add explanation what the error even means? Or what is the logic to fix it?

Comment: @PhilipRego I agree. I requested to delete my old answer because it didn't really contribute to a proper solution. From what I understand, IntelliJ does not rely on the pom.xml directly but builds up a structure in _.idea/libraries_ directory which is indeed generated from the POM file (and lost in reimport/refresh). 

You can modify these though Module Settings but it doesn't reflect on the POM contents, so only patching for IDE purposes to make stuff work but *not* correcting design/dependency flaws in actual source code or Maven project structure. See "select and remove it" comment below.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA 2021 from the main menu: Code > Analyze Code > Module Dependencies..

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Mikhails answer, here is **how to fix it**:

When you saw which modules have cyclic dependencies, right-click your project and

`Open Module Settings` -> *Expand the according module-group and select the module* -> `Dependencies` -> *select and remove it*

Comment: Does not actually remove it from the pom.xml.

Answer (score 4):

If the circular dependency is wrong then open Module Settings and remove it from the module(s) that should not have it.

If the dependency is correct then uncheck the `Enable annotation processing` box in `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Annotation Processors`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Going into Settings->Build->Compiler->Annotation Processors and disabling it solved it.

Allowing Test-A to depend on B, even though B depends on A

I'm using IntelliJ2019.1

But it's sad it doesn't seem to consider the maven test scope

Answer (score -1):

An alternative in order to solve this problem that worked for me (the above answers didn't).

Go to the `pom.xml` from the package / project that you have.
**Delete** the tag that is causing the issue.
You can find the dependecy with the issue in the console.

Hope it helps. :)